Integer overflow or inefficient coding?
I was trying to code the solution to this problem that goes "calculate the sum of all integers from 1 to (given) n"
My initial code was as follows, which works perfectly I believe
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    long long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}

However there was this sudden urge to make an "alternative" code and basically doing it without using a loop.
And as we all know, there is this formula in maths for sum of 1 to n, which is:sum(1, n) = ((n) * (n + 1)) / 2, right?
so the idea was to simply use this formula.
and although it works alright for small numbers, say 1000, there is an error (?) when I input relatively larger numbers like 1000000.
So like for 1000000, the answer should be 500,000,500,000, while through this second code, the output will be -363189984, which is weird, right?

Well, from what I know and understand, these kinds of "errors" occur due to the type of variables, say specifically for this case, long long, not being large enough to hold some number in them so they "crash" or whatever it's called.
However, in this case, I don't think it's all because of long long not being able to hold a number like 500,000,500,000, but, it's because of this operation of multiplying these two massive numbers (1000000 and 1000000+1), which causes this disaster to happen and hence the dodgy output.

So my question is,
First, am I right about that? if not what is the actual problem here with this code?
and Secondly, How can I fix this (like do I need to use a larger variable type or is it just that this code is by no means "efficient")

"calculate the sum of all integers from to (given) n" from what?

Your input is an int, your calculation presumably happens in an int (which overflows) and is promoted to long long afterwards. Solution: promote (cast or assign) to long long before applying formula.

Declare n as a long long, so all the calculation will be done with this type all the way.

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

It's more important to show us the code that does not work. Otherwise, what are we supposed to say? That the shown code works as intended? You already know/believe that. We can guess at which changes you made -- and which you did not but should have -- but that's only guesswork.

n is an int; n+1 is an int. So n * (n+1) will try to do operator * on ints ... and will overflow. sum = n * ( n + 1ull ) / 2 will "buy you time", but probably the best strategy is to be aware of the potential size of intermediate results and make sure they stay within the range of the types you are working with.

As in the other comments: yes, it's about the multiplication and (implicit) casting, so you should declare long long n, I know this is only a toy example, but the next thing one would optimize is to try to keep all intermediate results smaller than the numeric limit of the used type, so you would try to first divide n/2 (or (n+1)/2 if n is odd) and then do the multiplication.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai It's from 1 to n, I'll fix it. thank you for mentioning

@teapot418 Thank you! I didn't know that the calculation happens in the initial input type. I've now changed it to long long and it works alright.

@lastchance I see, thank you for explaining

Assuming the input, n has a 32-bit postive range of 1 .. 2147483647 and we have a 64-bit int type (long long or int64_t), then this should suffice:
#include <iostream>
#include <inttype.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int32_t n;
    cin >> n;

    int64_t sum = n;
    sum += 1;
    sum *= n;
    sum /= 2;

    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}

Notice that we cast 32-bit n to int64_t first, then we do all the math operations on it so we don't risk overflow.
Quick check. When I input 2147483647 into the above program, it prints out 2305843008139952128 which is (2147483647 * (2147483647+1))/2

It is also interesting to show that you are not using a loop but an existing formula for summing the integers of an arithmetic progression.

@kzsnyk , the very first idea was to use a loop, but I just wanted to try something different to see if I can avoid loops here by any chance.

What is happening is, effectivelly, that long long might not be able to hold your desired value as of numeric limits. Due to the fact that C and C++ code the numbers internally in two's complement mainly, while when there is an overflow it undefined behavior in most cases the visual result might be that it is output as a negative value (and this could hint you the UB).
In order to avoid these problems if you need an arbitrary size integer value you must use a library or write your own one.

This makes no sense.

What makes no sense? Numeric limits or the internal two's complement representation of signed numbers in C/C++? As both as true facts.

"when there is an overflow it could be represented as a negative value." is incorrect. Signed overflow in arithmetic causes undefined behavior instead (regardless of the representation chosen for the type).

thank you for the explanation! just a reminder that my first code (the one in my initial question in full and using "for") also uses long long for sum, but works alright and doesn't output a negative number. but the second one does. and the only difference however, is the second one is doing a multiplication operation which led me to believe that it has something to do with that.

@user17732522 I did not wanted to become pedantic on this, specially as OP mentioned negative representation but you are right, it causes UB but in most cases that UB gets visually as a negative number in practice. I'm going to edit to reflect this fact.

@Ksr - So it turns out that the difference is that the sum uses long long and the multiplication uses int. It is not the operations themselves that differ.

@Ksr as Selvie answered the casts will make it use the correct type buy you'll be ending in the same problem if you pass the int64_t limit. This is why I wrote about using a library or writing your own one in case your needs are beyond int64_t

"that long long might not be able to hold your desired value" -- The desired value for the specified case is a 13 digit number before the division by 2. The long long type is required to be able to hold all integers up to 18 digits, and even most of the 19 digit integers (more specifically, integers represented by 63 bits, which goes up to about 9.2e18). So it can hold the desired value.

My last comment on this: I just don't care being downvoted when I was the only one not being pedantic enough and telling the OP why he was getting those weird negative values. UB is UB but helps a lot to give hints on the possible UB effects (as happened here) rather than rant because of not being expressed correctly and sadly the latter helps less.

@StormByte "I just don't care being downvoted when I was the only one not being pedantic enough and telling the OP why he was getting those weird negative values." -- That's an assumption on your part. Maybe the downvotes are because your first statement has an error, one that could lead debugging down the wrong path, since it's not the long long variables that are the current problem. You could correct this by being less specific (changing "long long" to "the integer type") or by picking another type (e.g. int), but specifically blaming the use of the long long type is wrong.
